# strtok don't return nullptr

Tags: c++, strtok

Function strtok don't work like it should.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

This site tells that when strtok don't find the token it returns nullptr. And i don't know why in my code it don't.

Here is example code:

```
int main()
{
    char *c = "abcdefg";
    if (strtok(c, "^&") != NULL)
        printf("I found this in this string");
    else
        printf("I don;t");
    return 0;
}
```

It always print "I found this in this string" but in string "abcdefg" there is no char like '^' or '&'.

I compiled this in Code::Blocks and Visual Studio and always the same :/

Pls tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Read how the 1st call to `strtok` works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok  If it's the 1st call and no seperator(s) are found then the original string is the whole and only token.

Comment: Prefer `std::string` to C style character arrays.

Comment: Yes, it *does* work like it should. What it *doesn't* work like is apparently the way you *think* it should work. `strtok` doesn't return null if it can't find the token in a non-zero-length string, it returns the string itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strtok` function breaks up a string based on delimiters.  If there are no such delimiters in the string then there is nothing to break up, so the entire string is returned on the first call.  The second call (assuming the same delimiters are passed in) will then return NULL.  The only time the first call will return NULL is if you pass in an empty string.

The man page states:

> A  sequence  of calls to strtok() that operate on the same string
>   maintains a pointer that determines the point from which to start
>   searching    for  the  next  token.  **The first call to strtok() sets
>   this pointer to    point to the first byte of the string.**  The start
>   of the next token  is    determined  by  scanning forward for the next
>   nondelimiter byte in str.    If such a byte is found, it is taken as
>   the start of  the  next  token.    If  no  such byte is found, then
>   there are no more tokens, and strtok()    returns NULL.  (A string
>   that is empty or that contains only delimiters    will thus cause
>   strtok() to return NULL on the first call.)

Also, `strtok` modifies the string passed to it in order to split it up.  In your case, `c` points to a string literal which cannot be modified.  You should change it to a string:

```
char c[] = "abcdefg";
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Now i understand. I only think that information on this (popular?) site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ should be changed. Cuz this : "A null pointer is always returned when the end of the string (i.e., a null character) is reached in the string being scanned." is very confusing.

Comment: Nitpick: "*The only time the first call will return NULL is if you pass in an empty string.*" is not 100% correct. A first call with a string only consisting of delimiters will also return NULL

Answer (score 0):

The first call to strtok will never return NULL, unless the string passed is a NULL. The function searches for the first character which is not contained in the delimiter string and returns you that. Subsequent calls will return NULL tho, because the first "token" spans the whole string.

Comment: Suggest you try with a string `""` and then slightly rewrite that first sentence :-) NULL should only be passed on subsequent calls, not the first.